# SCSS variable not working after being transpiled

Tags: variables, sass, scope

I want to use a SASS variable in my SCSS file as follows:

```
$divCrossColor:green;

#divCross {
    z-index:1000;
    color: $divCrossColor;
    position: absolute;
    height:70vh;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-12px;
    margin-left:-13px;
}
```

This code is transpiled to css as follows:

```
#divCross {
    z-index: 1000;
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70vh;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
```

When I reload the webpage - after clearing the cache (cntl + shift + r) - the css does not appear. Scope is correct. Note, when I hard-code the color instead of using a variable, the scss is transpiled to css and when I load the webpage the css appears correctly. $cratching my head.  Also, I have the same issue when trying to use @rules such as @extend or @mixin/@include.  I'm using chrome but get the same result with edge. Can't find any issue in developer tools.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to what point your code is working or not. If you are able to compile sass into css the code you have should work. Please make clear if your compiler generates css from scss and how the result looks like exactly when setting the color as variable.